# jQuery DropDown with Textbox for input

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Is there any jQuery Plugin where i on click of the dropdown it shows the list of options. if there are not option that a user wants to select then i want to provide a way via a text box users should be able to type in the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery combobox() for this and for import file [**js**](http://forum.jquery.com/viewFile.do?fileId=14737000001017483&forumGroupId=14737000000003003)

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood)

Comment: how do we get the value when we submit? since we are using a select>option element

Comment: thanks. looks like its licensed. any idea of any free version?

Comment: sorry leave that.See here http://forum.jquery.com/viewFile.do?fileId=14737000001017483&forumGroupId=14737000000003003

Comment: thanks a lot. i think this works perfect. wondering how i missed it in the demos :D

Comment: will keep it open to see if others have any other references.

Comment: This is working on drop downs I create within the body, but it doesn't work with ones I am creating dynamically...